# I want to code with arduino, but do not have a good computer

Tags: arduino

Before I buy any arduino products, I want to make sure that I can use this website:

https://create.arduino.cc

to create the code for the arduino. The thing is, I do not know if I can use this to export the code to the arduino. Can someone please tell me if I can use it to program an actual arduino instead of simulating one?

By the way, the I do not have an actual computer, just a chromebook thinkpad (lenovo EDU series), so I can not use windows or apple software, it must be usable on the chrome web browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to install the Arduino Plugin for that to work.
If your computer is based on regular Windows and can run Chrome, that should work fine.

If your computer is a Chromebook, or Windows RT (for the ARM based surfaces) that will perhaps not work.

In general, if you can install your own software, it's better to use the Arduino IDE. Most computers, even pretty old ones, should be able to run the Arduino IDE, assuming you can download and install it.

If you can install the plugin on the website, then yes, the website tool will let you download your compiled code and upload it to a real Arduino board.

Comment: I now have a linux ubuntu laptop, it is old, but still works. Are there any software I can put on it that I can use to code an arduino?

Comment: Their is a linux version of the arduino IDE, which I have used on old laptops without issue.

Comment: Yes, the Arduino IDE works on Linux. You might be able to use apt-get install it.
Another option is to apt-get install gcc-avr, binutils-avr, avr-libc, and avrdude, and write the code yourself without the Arduino libraries. If you're a newbie who needs the Arduino tutorials, that's not as good an option.
An intermediate option, if the graphical IDE is too much for your computer, is the "arduino-mk" package, which allows you to use the Arduino libraries, but compile from the command line (presumably using vim or nano or emacs.)

Comment: Anything running linux is able to program Arduino. Be it old 486, Rapsberry Pi,... just anything with some free space on harddisk (or SD card, USB flash ...). Well newer computer can make it easier and faster, but it is only about convenience.